# Handling Bodies After Leaving Camera Viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In Libgdx in my game I have bodies that enter my camera viewport and then exit the viewport and never return.  Is it better for memory management to destroy these bodies and remove them from Arrays or sleep them?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation.

If you're asking what is ***generally*** the ***best***?  --- **Reusage**

When you reuse them, they will not stack up outside of the viewport, you won't need to create new bodies, and GarbageCollector won't need to collect anything.

But as I said, it depends on application. Mabye for your app letting them sleep there would be sufficient.